# Cleaning output from tribble or rbind (removing odd column names/ids)

Tags: r

**Goal:** I'm trying to create an easy summary statistics table where the rows are the same type of variable but from different datasets (and with different lengths).

**Problem:** When I use rbind or tribble to combine rows created out of a function, the output is odd.

**1. Data**

```
Age1 <- data.frame(c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25))
colnames(Age1) <- c("Age")
Age2 <- data.frame(c(5, 10, 15))
colnames(Age2) <- c("Age")
Age3 <- data.frame(c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30))
colnames(Age3) <- c("Age")
```

**2. Function to extract summary statistics**

I create a function to extract summary statistics (length, mean, standard deviation, minimum, maximum, and the data frame's name):

```
summary.stats <- function(x, d){  
  RowName <- deparse(substitute(d))
  N <- length(x[!is.na(x)])
  Mu <- mean(x)
  Sigma <- sd(x)
  Min <- min(x, na.rm = T)
  Max <- max(x, na.rm = T)
  Row <- cbind(RowName, N, Mu, Sigma, Min, Max)
  print(Row)
}
```

**3a. Use tribble to combine results**

I then create a tribble from the function run for each of the datasets.

```
tribble(
  ~ DF.Name, ~ N, ~ Mean, ~ St.Dev., ~ Min, ~ Max,
  summary.stats(Age1$Age, Age1),
  summary.stats(Age2$Age, Age2),
  summary.stats(Age3$Age, Age3)
)
```

I receive the following result:

```
     RowName N   Mu   Sigma              Min Max 
[1,] "Age1"  "5" "15" "7.90569415042095" "5" "25"
     RowName N   Mu   Sigma Min Max 
[1,] "Age2"  "3" "10" "5"   "5" "15"
     RowName N   Mu     Sigma              Min Max 
[1,] "Age3"  "6" "17.5" "9.35414346693485" "5" "30"
```

Above each row, the column names are printed. I'd like to get rid the column names in the output (maybe with exception for the top row of column names).

**3b. Use rbind to combine results**

I could use rbind instead of tribble to print the results together:

```
rbind(
  summary.stats(Age1$Age, Age1),
  summary.stats(Age2$Age, Age2),
  summary.stats(Age3$Age, Age3)
)
```

But then I once again get an odd result:

```
     RowName N   Mu   Sigma              Min Max 
[1,] "Age1"  "5" "15" "7.90569415042095" "5" "25"
     RowName N   Mu   Sigma Min Max 
[1,] "Age2"  "3" "10" "5"   "5" "15"
     RowName N   Mu     Sigma              Min Max 
[1,] "Age3"  "6" "17.5" "9.35414346693485" "5" "30"
     RowName N   Mu     Sigma              Min Max 
[1,] "Age1"  "5" "15"   "7.90569415042095" "5" "25"
[2,] "Age2"  "3" "10"   "5"                "5" "15"
[3,] "Age3"  "6" "17.5" "9.35414346693485" "5" "30"
```

Any suggestions as to how to clean up the output would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Step 3a is giving me the following error: `Error: invalid specification: had 3 elements and 6 columns`

Comment: Yeah, I did get that too. I'm not entirely sure what to make of it, but it should still be printing output. I don't think the error is likely to affect how the column names are displayed, however.

Comment: I also noticed that the tribble function is not printing the column names that I tried to assign it, but again, I think these are unrelated issues. Of course, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to do what you want. Changes made:

- Remove the `print` call from inside the function. This was responsible for the additional prints when running rbind
- Change the `cbind` to `tibble`. This creates a data frame, which is more amenable to `rbind` (or `dplyr::bind_rows`) than the character vector that `cbind` was making.

This gives:

```
summary.stats <- function(x, d){  
  RowName <- deparse(substitute(d))
  N <- length(x[!is.na(x)])
  Mu <- mean(x)
  Sigma <- sd(x)
  Min <- min(x, na.rm = T)
  Max <- max(x, na.rm = T)
  Row <- tibble(RowName, N, Mu, Sigma, Min, Max)
}

rbind(
  summary.stats(Age1$Age, Age1),
  summary.stats(Age2$Age, Age2),
  summary.stats(Age3$Age, Age3)
)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  RowName     N    Mu Sigma   Min   Max
  <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Age1        5  15.0  7.91  5.00  25.0
2 Age2        3  10.0  5.00  5.00  15.0
3 Age3        6  17.5  9.35  5.00  30.0
```